# Create RAID 5 with 2 new and 2 data disks without losing data

Tags: raid, raid5, raid1

I would like to create a RAID 5 for my file storage. For that purpose, I currently use 2 drives without any RAID configuration. I would like to upgrade to a RAID 5. I want to add 2 new (and empty) disks. Is it possible to create the RAID without me losing data from the 2 almost full disks that I currently use? I know about RAID 1 to RAID 5, but as that does not create a normal RAID 5 I am wondering if there is a better solution to my problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: well, a raid 5 needs 3 disk at least, even if you can create the raid 5 i aint sure if you can do that, i would suggest to create the raid, copy the data, add the other disk, and repeat

Comment: you mean create the raid 1 and then add data and so on?

Comment: RAID 5 is pretty much dead at this point. It should no longer be used if you care about not losing your data. Make a RAID 10 and relax.

Comment: losing data hat would be on the RAID config would be bad but not terrible. For important data, I prefer to rely on backups anyways.

Comment: **What kind of RAID software/hardware?**  If Linux+mdadm I think you could probably create a RAID5 of the two new disk with a 'missing' third disk.  Then migrate the data from one of the drives over, then move the empty disk into the array, and then repeat for the fourth disk, this time 'growing' the array.  You would want to have very good backups before you try that though.

Comment: Oh yea, I forgot to mention that I want to use a software raid. The mdadm solution sounds very fitting for my problem. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

when a RAID 5 array is created, the RAID controller wipes out any data on the drives since they are not RAID compatible. RAID 5 works by using a parity bit across all the drives, so since the two drives you already have data on do not have any parity data, the drives will be wiped when you create the array. 
Your best option is to back up all the existing data to an external drive, then add the two new drives and create the array. Then you will have to add the data back to the array. This method will require you to reinstall your operating system since the newly created array does not have any data on it.